# dc.js, fill table with data from object dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a problem concerning filling a dc.js table with data. [The documentation allows for 2 ways for doing this](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html#columns__anchor).

However, my data is formatted so that element of the 3D-data-array is an object. In this object I store some information about the cell (datatype, faulty, empty etc) and the value (of course).

So instead of accessing a value by `array[row][column]`, I access it by `array[row][column].csvValue`.

This means that I cannot use the proposed way to create the function, which sets the column. (see the link from above)

```
chart.columns([function(d) { return d.date; }, ... ]);
```

So what I would like my array to look like is (if i have 3 columns):

```
chart.columns([function(d) { return d[0].cellValue; }, 
               function(d) { return d[1].cellValue; },
               function(d) { return d[2].cellValue; } ]);
```

To create this array dynamically I loop over each column and add a function to the array.
This approach cannot work, because I have a variable `i` inside the inner function, which is undefined outside of this loop. But I cannot think of a way of building this array without having the variable for the row `i` in my function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < cellInfo[0].length; i++) {
    columnArray[i] = function(d) {return d[i].cellValue; /* d[i] produces the error */};
}
```

I have created 2 jsfiddles: [one where you can see my error in the console](http://jsfiddle.net/tbamW/248/), and [one working example using just a 3D-array without an object inside each cell](http://jsfiddle.net/tbamW/247/).

Comment: i would suggest to use a closure like that: http://jsfiddle.net/tbamW/249/

Comment: works like a charm, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As andiwand pointed out, a closure is needed to solve my problem. I have also edited the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbamW/250/) (by adding brackets around the function).

The critical line, where a closure is added is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    columnArray[i] = (function(i){ return function(d) {return d[i].cellValue;}; })(i);
}
```

An interesting read on this topic is the [closure documentation from developers.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake). It provides insight to scoping of variables and closures in JS and their implications.